# how to get last changed revision number and last changed date of source code in maven pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I'm able to get the buildNumber and build time stamp in manifest.mf file by configuring as shown below:

```
<manifestEntries>
<Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>
<revision>${buildNumber}</revision> 
</manifestEntries>
```

Can you please suggest me how to get the last changed revision and last changed date of scm?

```
<scm>
<last-changed-revision>0</last-changed-revision>
<last-changed-date>N/A</last-changed-date>
</scm>
```

Comment: Which SCM? There may be a generic solution, but probably helpful if you specify what you're using.

Comment: SVN location from where Maven will check out the source code

Comment: Not sure about date, but SVN revision number is covered here: http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/add-svn-revision-to-manifest.html. Also closely related: [How to display SVN version in Maven usng the build-number plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874813/how-to-display-svn-version-in-maven-usng-the-build-number-plugin)

Comment: We are able to get the latest revision number from here but can you please tell me how to get previous revision number

Comment: You mean the last-but-one SVN revision number and date? I suspect that would be very hard to get - why do you need it?

Comment: yes..i need both the revision numbers

Comment: yes..i need both the revision numbers