# maven-buildnumber-plugin get full svn version

Tags: maven, svn, version-control, build

When typing

```
svnversion . /dev/products/prod_name/trunk
```

I get the full version scheme, like `22330:22355MS` (when using it without the trail URL, I still get `22330:22355M`).
The `maven-buildnumber-plugin` from mojohaus only gives me the first part of the revision, and oddly incremented by one (i.e., `22331` instead of `22330`).

In my `pom.xml`:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://svn.our.url/dev/products/prod_name/branches/my_branch</connection>
    <url>https://svn.our.url/dev/products/prod_name/branches/my_branch</url>
</scm>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
        <doCheck>false</doCheck>
        <format>{0,date,dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}__{1}</format>
        <items>
            <item>timestamp</item>
            <item>scmVersion</item>
        </items>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

What is happening here and how can I get the full version number?

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874813/how-to-display-svn-version-in-maven-usng-the-build-number-plugin?

Comment: Yes I did. But I'm using scmVersion, not buildNumber. I did read in one of the comments though, that it the plugin uses `svn info` and not `svnversion`. That doesn't seem to give you the full thing...