# SVN revision number and timestamp

Tags: svn, maven, timestamp, revision, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I'm trying to display the latest SVN revision number and timestamp on the title bar of a web application. My current code displays the revision number but not timestamp. Both are not coming together. I'm using the following code.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <executions>

    <execution>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>create</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <useLastCommittedRevision>true</useLastCommittedRevision>
      </configuration>
    </execution>

    <execution>
      <id>generate-timestamp</id>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>create</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>

  </executions>
</plugin>
```

It displays the revision number only. From the jsp I'm accessing the value like this

```
${initParam['build']}
```

Then it shows the revision. 
What is the modification required to display revision and timestamp. And how can I access the timestamp value?

Comment: Why do you have 2 executions with the same goal? Also, do you have command line svn client installed?

Comment: This answer says that If I need both values, I should use 2 executions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319248/maven-buildnumber-plugin-svn-revision-available-only-when-not-using-format. Yes I've command line svn client.

Comment: I checked the link you referenced.  Your configuration matches neither that of the accepted answer nor [this additional answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12887414/944849) showing two executions.  If you add the missing elements (format, items, etc), does it work?

Comment: Reading maven-buildnumber-plugin manual, I think it only gives the scm buildnumber and revision at maven scope, there must be some extra configuration you have in your code so that you can access it on jsp (eg: web.xml, properties file or such)

Comment: @user944849 I tried it like that initially, but it won't work.

Comment: @gerrytan Do you have any idea how can we get the values in pom ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using like this now:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>create</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <format>{0} - {1,date,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}</format>
    <items>
        <item>scmVersion</item>
        <item>timestamp</item>
    </items>
</configuration>
```

And access the value from jsp like this:

```
${initParam['build']}
```

This shows the SVN revision number first and then the timestamp.