# read svn revision at compile time with gwt eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, svn, gwt

**situation**

I try to read the SVN revision number in a gwt project in eclipse IDE at compile time.
I would like just to use the gwt eclipse plugin.
When I've googled my problem I could only find solutions with maven.
I have subclipse installed, maybe that helps.

**problem & tried solution**

When I'm writting code in c/c++ I get the SVN revision like that:

```
-D'MYVER="$(shell svnversion -c .)"'
```

I can not find a similar argument for the gwt compiler. I tested the same argument as for the gcc, but it won't work.

**question**

- Is there a similar argument for the gwt compiler?
- Is there a way to get the svn revision without maven?
- Maybe there is a solution with subclipse plugin?

Comment: I think I have to read into maven. If someone has a solution without it, I'm still interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution**

I have to work with maven or something similar, there is no way with the gwt compiler.

Here another article showing how to realize this with maven:
[SVN revision number and timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374674/svn-revision-number-and-timestamp)